# App shows blank screen

Tags: android, freeze

In my app I have some buttons that when I clicking on Them application getting data from the network and showing in to the listView.
problem is that sometimes when I clicking on the button screen will be freezing and showing the blank black screen.

this is the error of logcat:

> 09-20 11:17:12.437: E/InputDispatcher(469): channel 'a6941398 com.employment.app.find_work.recruitment/com.employment.app.find_work.recruitment.ActivityFirst (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
>
> 09-20 11:17:12.449: E/InputDispatcher(469): channel 'a6aa7d08 Loading please wait (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!

```
public class ActivityFirst extends Activity {

public static Handler        handler       = new Handler();
public static ProgressDialog progress;

private static final int     TIME_INTERVAL = 2000;         // # milliseconds, desired time passed between two back presses.
private long                 mBackPressed;

ImageView                    img_agahi_estekhdami;
ImageView                    img_akhbar_estekhdami;
ImageView                    img_akhabar_eghtesadi;
ImageView                    img_karafarini;
ImageView                    img_setting;
ImageView                    img_about;

public myAsynctask           myAsynctask;
public myAsynctask2          myAsynctask2;
public myAsynctask3          myAsynctask3;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    boolean skipWelcome = G.preferences.getBoolean("SKIP_WELCOME", false);
    if ( !skipWelcome)
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(ActivityFirst.this, Welcome.class);
        startActivity(intent);

        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = G.preferences.edit();
        editor.putBoolean("SKIP_WELCOME", true);
        editor.commit();
    }

    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);

    img_agahi_estekhdami = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img_agahi_estekhdami);
    img_akhbar_estekhdami = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img_akhbar_estekhdami);
    img_akhabar_eghtesadi = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img_akhabar_eghtesadi);
    img_karafarini = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img_karafarini);
    img_setting = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img_setting);
    img_about = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img_about);

    try
    {

        img_agahi_estekhdami.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {

                Intent intent3 = new Intent(ActivityFirst.this, ServerChoise.class);
                startActivity(intent3);

            }
        });

        img_akhbar_estekhdami.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {

                myAsynctask = new myAsynctask();

                if ( !myAsynctask.isCancelled())
                {

                    myAsynctask.execute();
                }

            }
        });

        img_akhabar_eghtesadi.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                myAsynctask2 = new myAsynctask2();

                if ( !myAsynctask2.isCancelled())
                {

                    myAsynctask2.execute();
                }
            }
        });

        img_karafarini.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                myAsynctask3 = new myAsynctask3();

                if ( !myAsynctask3.isCancelled())
                {

                    myAsynctask3.execute();
                }
            }
        });

        img_setting.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(ActivityFirst.this, Setting.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_left, R.anim.slide_out_right);
            }
        });

        img_about.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(ActivityFirst.this, About.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_left, R.anim.slide_out_right);
            }
        });

    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Toast.makeText(G.context, "Error 103", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

}


@Override
public void onBackPressed()
{
    if (mBackPressed + TIME_INTERVAL > System.currentTimeMillis())
    {
        super.onBackPressed();
        android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
        return;
    }
    else {
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Press back key to Exit", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    mBackPressed = System.currentTimeMillis();
}


public void showLoadingDialog() {

    progress = new ProgressDialog(ActivityFirst.this);
    progress.setTitle("Loading please Wait");
    progress.setMessage("Loading");
    progress.show();
    progress.setCancelable(true);
}


//---------------------------------------------------------------

public class myAsynctask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>
{

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        showLoadingDialog();
    }


    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

        Intent intent = new Intent(ActivityFirst.this, RecruitmentActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("INPUT", "http://www.eghtesadonline.com/fa/rss/relatedeconomy");
        startActivity(intent);
        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_left, R.anim.slide_out_right);

        return null;
    }


    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        progress.dismiss();
    }

}


//-----------------------------------------------------------------
public class myAsynctask2 extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>
{

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        showLoadingDialog();
    }


    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

        Intent intent = new Intent(ActivityFirst.this, RecruitmentActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("INPUT", "http://www.eghtesadonline.com/fa/rss/economy");
        startActivity(intent);
        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_left, R.anim.slide_out_right);

        return null;
    }


    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        progress.dismiss();
    }

}


//--------------------------------------------------------------------

public class myAsynctask3 extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>
{

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        showLoadingDialog();
    }


    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

        Intent intent = new Intent(ActivityFirst.this, RecruitmentActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("INPUT", "http://www.eghtesadonline.com/fa/rss/management");
        startActivity(intent);
        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_left, R.anim.slide_out_right);

        return null;
    }


    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        progress.dismiss();
    }

}
```

Comment: there might be a memory leak or may be because you are calling `startActivity(intent);` from `doInBackground()` method.

Comment: How can I find if memory leak ?